# How to send email from docker container to host postfix with bsd-mailx?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, mailx

I have a running `postfix` mailserver on my `ubuntu` host. I might lateron replace it also with a docker container, but for migration, I want to stick with the host postfix first.

How can I send emails from a `docker container` to the host postfix, if I want to minimize image size?

I tried installing `bsd-mailx` inside the container, as is has a small package size.

In general, I could now send emails with:
`echo "test header" | mail -s "test body" my@mail.com`

But how can I tell command in the docker container to actually send the mail to the host system? Or would I have to mount/bind something from the hosts' postfix into the container? So that mailx sends the mail to the mount?

Comment: The `mailx` command operates by passing the message off to `/usr/sbin/sendmail`. You could provide that command using something like [`ssmtp`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSMTP), and configure `ssmtp` to hand off the mail to your postfix container using SMTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mail/mailx both invoke a binary called sendmail. That means that you need to install an MTA which is offering that particular interface.

- postfix
- exim
- maybe nullmailer

Comment: Can't I just mount `sendmail` from host into the container?

Comment: That could work :) Tip: sendmail might be in different locations: /usr/sbin/sendmail and /usr/lib/sendmail

Comment: Unfortunately it was not possible to simply mount sendmail from host. I thus installed `msmtp-mta` and can now send mails to hosts postfix with: `echo "Subject: test" | sendmail --from=noreplay@my-company.com --host=host.docker.internal my@company.com`